# No main method when there is actually one in the class

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

There's lots of questions like this but I've read through 95% of them roughly XD
Basically my code HAS a main class, yet it says it doesn't, What's going on?

```
public class RegisterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public RegisterGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    PaySafeTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    TitleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FirstNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    LastNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    EmailAddLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    UsernameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    PasswordLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ConfimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    TitleList = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    TitleField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    FirstNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    LastNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    EmailAddField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    UsernameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    PasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    ConfirmationField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    PasswordMatchLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    MatchResult = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    NextBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    PaySafeTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    PaySafeTitle.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/PaySafeLogo.png"))); // NOI18N
    getContentPane().add(PaySafeTitle, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 11, 380, 37));

    TitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    TitleLabel.setText("Title:");
    getContentPane().add(TitleLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 54, 98, 23));

    FirstNameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    FirstNameLabel.setText("First name:");
    getContentPane().add(FirstNameLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 83, 98, 23));

    LastNameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    LastNameLabel.setText("Last name:");
    getContentPane().add(LastNameLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 112, 98, 23));

    EmailAddLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    EmailAddLabel.setText("Email Address:");
    getContentPane().add(EmailAddLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 141, 98, 23));

    UsernameLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    UsernameLabel.setText("Username:");
    getContentPane().add(UsernameLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 170, 98, 23));

    PasswordLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    PasswordLabel.setText("Password:");
    getContentPane().add(PasswordLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 199, 98, 23));

    ConfimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ConfimationLabel.setText("Confirm Password:");
    getContentPane().add(ConfimationLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 228, 98, 23));

    TitleList.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Ms", "Dr", "Other..." }));
    getContentPane().add(TitleList, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 55, 100, -1));

    TitleField.setEditable(false);
    getContentPane().add(TitleField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(218, 55, 172, -1));
    getContentPane().add(FirstNameField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 84, 278, -1));
    getContentPane().add(LastNameField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 113, 278, -1));
    getContentPane().add(EmailAddField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 142, 278, -1));
    getContentPane().add(UsernameField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 171, 278, -1));

    PasswordField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            PasswordFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(PasswordField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 200, 170, -1));
    getContentPane().add(ConfirmationField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(112, 229, 170, -1));

    PasswordMatchLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    PasswordMatchLabel.setText("Password match:");
    getContentPane().add(PasswordMatchLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 200, 100, 20));

    MatchResult.setEditable(false);
    MatchResult.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(MatchResult, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 230, 100, -1));
    do{
        if((PasswordField.getPassword())==(ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
        MatchResult.setText("MATCH");
    }
    else{
        MatchResult.setText("NO MATCH");
    }
    while((PasswordField.getPassword())!(ConfirmationField.getPassword()));

    NextBtn.setText("Next");
    getContentPane().add(NextBtn, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(180, 260, -1, -1));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void PasswordFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RegisterGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel ConfimationLabel;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField ConfirmationField;
private javax.swing.JTextField EmailAddField;
private javax.swing.JLabel EmailAddLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField FirstNameField;
private javax.swing.JLabel FirstNameLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField LastNameField;
private javax.swing.JLabel LastNameLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField MatchResult;
private javax.swing.JButton NextBtn;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField PasswordField;
private javax.swing.JLabel PasswordLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel PasswordMatchLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel PaySafeTitle;
private javax.swing.JTextField TitleField;
private javax.swing.JLabel TitleLabel;
private javax.swing.JComboBox TitleList;
private javax.swing.JTextField UsernameField;
private javax.swing.JLabel UsernameLabel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

as you can see about 3/4 of the way down there is a main method, but netbeans doesn't seem to recognise that it is there :/
Yes this is made using the GUI builder, It's for a class project and as we're all relatively new it's quicker than building it from scratch.

Comment: What error does netbeans return?

Comment: Right click project > Refresh?

Comment: Your code is ok, so I suggest you to try another IDE (eclipse, intellij)... and, of course, stop using net beans GUI builder, especially in net beans :) It locks source code generated via GUI builder and prevents developer from editing it. Well, at least it was like this when I tried to use it.

Comment: @mr.nothing: This comment is not constructive.  To suggest that the problem is primary within Netbeans itself is not likely to be true.  Simply asking the OP to switch IDE's simply asks him to do busywork without having any understanding of the actual problem.  Moreover, Scene Builder is a perfectly valid GUI development tool when used within its constraints.  It is definitely possible to co-develop an FXML-based GUI with a controller in Netbeans using Scene Builder.  To suggest that it isn't possible is simply a different kind of ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line may be messing up the parser:

```
while((PasswordField.getPassword())!(ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
```

It is incorrect syntax.  Perhaps you meant:

```
while((PasswordField.getPassword()) != (ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
```

While the syntax is now better, it's still logically incorrect.  You can't use `!=` (or `==`) to compare `char[]` contents like that; on objects, those operators determine if the references are (or are not) pointing to the same object.  You'll need another method to compare the contents, [`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5b%5d,%20char%5b%5d%29).

Also, your braces are off a bit in your do-while loop.  Your code:

```
do{
    if((PasswordField.getPassword())==(ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
    MatchResult.setText("MATCH");
}
else{
    MatchResult.setText("NO MATCH");
}
while((PasswordField.getPassword())!(ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
```

Here, the brace before the `else` matches `do`, so you get `else` without `if` and `while` expected.  Additionally, the `;` after the `if` condition is unnecessary and wrong, because it counts as the `if` statement body, not `MatchResult.setText("MATCH")` -- remove it.

Try

```
do {
    if (Arrays.equals(PasswordField.getPassword(), ConfirmationField.getPassword()))
        MatchResult.setText("MATCH");
    else {
        MatchResult.setText("NO MATCH");
    }
}
while(!Arrays.equals(PasswordField.getPassword(), ConfirmationField.getPassword()));
```

Note the indentation, which helps see where the braces begin and end blocks better than before.

Comment: I've included your code and it has atleast allowed me to run the program, however I think my "do while" loop is wrong or my logic somewhere else is messed up, I would like the "MatchResult" to only display "MATCH" when both the passwords in "PasswordField" and in "ConfirmationField" are the same, at the moment it only ever says "MATCH" :/
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the entry point in your IDE.